# A more efficient way to code this program

Tags: java, arraylist

This Program WAS homework. We have already finished it and are good to go. I was wondering if there is a more streamlined way of writing this program? The program is called Interleave and what it does is take two ArrayLists and combine them so that every other element in the first one is from the second ArrayList. Sounds simple, and it was, we used the Iterator to go through and add the necessary elements. But the code is BLOCKY. It seems to me that there has to be a better way to write this, right? Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Interleave
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Collections.addAll(a1, 10, 20, 30);

    ArrayList<Integer> a2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Collections.addAll(a2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

    System.out.println(a1);
    System.out.println(a2);

    System.out.println(interleave(a1, a2));

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] words =
    { "how", "are", "you?" };

    for (String s : words)
    {
        list.add(s);
    }

}

public static ArrayList<Integer> interleave(ArrayList<Integer> a1,
        ArrayList<Integer> a2)
{
    Iterator<Integer> it = a2.iterator();
    int i = 1;
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        int val = it.next();
        if (a1.size() >= i)
        {
            a1.add(i, val);
        } else
        {
            a1.add(val);
        }
        i += 2;
    }
    return a1;

}
```

}

Comment: Java, as a language, is pretty verbose and "blocky". Get used to it. ;-)

Comment: @Santa, well, at least his project didn't involve Legos, that would have gotten messy.  Maybe even 'blocky' ;)

Comment: You could replace the Iterator-while loop with a for each-loop, which would save you a whole whopping line! ;)

Comment: There isn't a much better way to structure your code. However, you can make it more efficient (i.e. faster) if you are allowed to create a third array for the result and add items into that, since inserting elements into an existing array is slow.

Comment: @cularis lol. Yeah I could i guess. I just couldn't believe that the end result would be that big.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> interleave(ArrayList<Integer> a1, ArrayList<Integer> a2)
{
    Iterator<Integer> it1 = a1.iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> it2 = a2.iterator();
    ArrayList<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (it1.hasNext() || it2.hasNext())
    {
        if (it1.hasNext()) { output.add( it1.next() ); }
        if (it2.hasNext()) { output.add( it2.next() ); }
    }

    return output;    
}
```

Comment: The while condition should be `||` not `&&` to allow for different length lists.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: +1 Because the real reason the OP's code is blocky is that he updated things in place.

Answer (score 1):

Efficiency is more important than how the code looks. Every time you add an element at index i, every element after that index needs to be moved up by one index by the ArrayList, since it uses an array as its underlying data structure. This code would be a lot more efficient if it used a LinkedList which avoids this problem, or if you created a third array of size (first array + second array) and just added the elements to that one. Then again, you also have to consider space, so making another array increases space requirements.

Even if you stick with your current approach, you should increase the capacity of the array BEFORE adding all the elements. That way, the array's capacity will already be large enough to add all of the elements from the other array, and it won't (potentially) need to be increased multiple times.

Hope that helps.

edit:

You could also reconfigure your array in advance such that every second spot was already empty, which would save you from the array shifting problem that I described earlier.

Comment: Efficiency is far less important than how code looks. Clean code is less likely to be buggy code, and it's easier to maintain. If you get to the point where your code is not sufficiently efficient to do its job, profile it and fix the parts that matter. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil.](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Comment: @nmichaels - You're misusing the premature optimization quote. Each situation is different, and therefore has its own set of guidelines. Furthermore it's impossible for any of us to say what would be "sufficiently efficient to do its job" since this was a school exercise, and the OP did not go into detail about requirements. As such, we would be remiss to not mention an overall better solution.

Comment: @nmichaels - I should also add that premature optimization is NOT an excuse for using poor programming practices, which is what you are advocating. When possible, programmers should choose data structures wisely, and should code such that their code is readable, maintainable, and efficient. Those things should be balanced depending on the situation; premature optimization is irrelevant.

Comment: @nmichaels I think you nailed it. I am constantly trying to find the most efficient way to code things. When I said blocky i meant blockier than it could be. Thank you all for your helpful suggestions.

Comment: @kyleM I guess my biggest problem with using Arrays is size and declaring that ahead of time without having a ton of empty indexes. I try to make my code so that it is easily interchangeable with different formats but then I have to address the size issue again.

Comment: @KyleM: I wasn't taking issue with the substance of your answer (which is why I didn't downvote it) just the first sentence. I was not advocating inappropriate use of data structures or poor programming practices. On the contrary; I was advocating good programming practices. As it turns out, you were too. You just started it with an unfortunate statement.

Comment: @kreeSeeker you're already using arrays. An ArrayList uses an array as its backing data store. An ArrayList is just an abstraction that makes it easier to use an array. Also, Lucas's post shows an implementation of the concept I described, except that Lucas should have gone further by setting the initial capacity of the array, as I described in this post.

Comment: @nmichaels, Fair enough. My first sentence was a sweeping generalization that I should not have made.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your `interleave` function assumes a *specific* list implementation (`ArrayList`) and a *specific* type that it *must* contain (`Integer`). You can generalize this function by using generics:

```
public static <T> List<T> interleave(List<T> first, List<T> second)
{
    Iterator<T> it = second.iterator();
    int i = 1;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        T val = it.next();
        if (first.size() >= i)
            first.add(i, val);
        else
            first.add(val);
        i += 2;
    }

    return first;
}
```

Comment: Although, this still forces the two lists to contain the same type.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can reduce the amount of code much. It probably can't be made to be too much faster either. I would however suggest some other improvements:

1. It's not a good practice to mutate an object that you pass in if you're returning another one.
2. You could just use `List` instead of `ArrayList` so any type of `List` can be passed in.
3. You could use generics to not make it specific to a list of `Integer`.

These combined would yield something like this:

```
public static <T> List<T> interleave(List<T> a1, List<T> a2) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(a1.size() + a2.size());
    Iterator<T> it1 = a1.iterator();
    Iterator<T> it2 = a2.iterator();

    while (it1.hasNext() || it2.hasNext()) {
        if (it1.hasNext()) {
            list.add(it1.next());
        }
        if (it2.hasNext()) {
            list.add(it2.next());
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Good point but because it is homework I would have to stay in the rules of the project.

Comment: @kreeSeeker It can be made much faster, as I described in my post. Simply using a LinkedList would provably increase your speed as the number of elements increased.